# ref returning null value reactjs. How to handle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm opening modal from another component by using ref in reactjs. for that I'm doing below code.

```
otpModalRef = ({onOpenModal}) => {
       this.showModal = onOpenModal;
}
```

and in render below code

```
<div className="otp_modal">
    <Otp ref={this.otpModalRef} ></Otp>
</div>
```

& then calling in register function by `this.showModal();` It's working fine. but when I clicked on login button it's giving me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onOpenModal' of null`. Below is login and register functions.

```
    login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     axios.post('/api/signin', { 
                    user:this.state.user,
                    password:this.state.login_pass,
                })
      .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.context.router.history.push({
                    pathname:'/',
                });

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
}

register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();     
    axios.post('/api/user/add', { 
                    firstname: this.state.fname,
                    lastname:this.state.lname,
                    email:this.state.emailaddress,
                    password:this.state.password,
                    mobile:this.state.mobile 
                },              
            )
      .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.showModal();
      })
}
```

Not getting what is the issue? If I comment the `otpModalRef` it redirects to homepage but if I keep the gives this null error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call React.createRef() to create a handle and not like you did in roure code.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.otpModalRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: Yes I saw that but without adding this my modal is opening so I thought It doesnt need. Now working fine. Thanks.

Comment: but now getting this.showModal undefined because of this

Comment: You can change the this.showmodal with this.otpModalRef.show()